# how to merge two different columns in oracle

Tags: oracle

Team,

I m looking to merge 3 different columns in oracle, and output as target table from source. Tried using UNION operator, but could not achieve and a bit confused to bring maths , stats and computers to bring it as one column.Please help

Source table

```
**STUDENT_ID    MATHS   STATS   COMPUTERS**
1           90      80      70
2           60      50      70
```

Target table

```
**STUDENT_ID    SUBJECT MARKS**
  1             maths       90
  1             stats       80
  1             computers   70
  2             maths       60
  2             stats       50
  2             computers   70
```

Answer (score 4):

This should give you the result you expected.

```
insert into target_table
(select student_ID,'maths',MATHS from source_table
union all
select student_ID,'stats',STATS from source_table
union all
select student_ID,'computers',COMPUTERS from source_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me !!

> ```
> insert into targettable  ( student_id , Subjects ,marks) 
> select student_id, 'Maths', maths from sourcetable  
> union
> select student_id, 'Stats', stats from sourcetable
> union 
> select student_id,'Computer',computer from sourcetable
> ```